# Scheme Procedure that takes an argument and outputs a value

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a procedure called `bal-val` that has to take in a single argument and output the value of the ball. The values for the balls are `R = 5`, `G=4`, `B = 3`, and `W = 1`.

The code I have is:

```
(define (bal-val n)
        (if (= n R))
            (= n 5)
            (if (= n G))
                (= n 4)
                (if (= n B))
                    (= n 3)
                    (if (= n W))
                        (= n 1))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This site is for asking questions on specific problems with code. What you are looking for I think is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

First of all `(= n 5)` applys the function `=` to the constant `5` and the variable `n`. Therefore it returns a Boolean value, it does not set n to be 5.

The main issue though is wrong use of [Predicates](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html):

`=` predicate is used to check whether two numbers are equal. If you supply anything else (but a number) it will raise an error.

The `eq?` predicate is used to check whether its two parameters respresent the same object in memory.

The `equal?` predicate tests for same value in primitive types and can also check two lists, vectors, etc.

This is what you are trying to do:

```
(define (bal-val n)
  (if (equal? n 'R)
      5
      (if (equal? n 'G)
          4
          (if (equal? n 'B)
              3
              (if (equal? n 'W)
                  1
                  (error 'not_found))))))
```

You might want to use [cond](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) in this case as it resembles switch behavior more naturally. Done like so:

```
(define (bal-val-cond n)
  (cond ((equal? n 'R) 5)
        ((equal? n 'G) 4)
        ((equal? n 'B) 3)
        ((equal? n 'W) 1)
        (else (error 'not_found))))
```

**coding 101 - ALWAYS indent your code** correctly, it makes it understandable and with time errors will stand out and you will be able to spot them much quicker.